# How to push data to ember's store of a model that have a JSONSerializer as it's Serializer insted of JSONAPISerializer or RESTSerializer in Ember js?

Tags: serialization, ember.js, ember-data

For a model which is using **JSONAPISerializer** as it's Serializer pushing a record for that model

into the store is done by **store.push(dataInJSONAPISerializerFormat)**

https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.3/classes/DS.Store/methods/push?anchor=push

method.But for the model which is using **RESTSerializer** as it's Serializer pushing a record for that

model into the store is done by **store.pushPayload("modelName",dataInRESTSerializerFormat)**

https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.3/classes/DS.Store/methods/pushPayload?anchor=pushPayload
 method.

But incase of **JSONSerializer both of them are not working?** Can anyone Help me?

Answer (score 4):

You misunderstood the difference between `push` and `pushPayload` methods of DS.Store.

The [`push` method](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.3/classes/DS.Store/methods/push?anchor=push) *"is used to notify Ember Data's store of new or updated records that exist in the backend."* It expects a *"normalized JSON API document"*. Normalized means that it must not only be compliant with [JSON API specification](http://jsonapi.org/) but also follow some even stricter conventions.

If your payload is not already a *normalized JSON API document* you have to convert it to some. This is normally done by a Serializer. It does not matter if this Serializer is extended of [DS.JSONSerializer](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/release/classes/DS.JSONSerializer), [DS.RestSerializer](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/release/classes/DS.RESTSerializer) or just the base [DS.Serializer](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/release/classes/DS.Serializer) class. Even if you are using a [DS.JSONAPISerializer](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/release/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer) you might need to serialize your payload if it's not normalized (e.g. `type` is not pluralized).

The [`pushPayload` method](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.3/classes/DS.Store/methods/pushPayload?anchor=pushPayload) *"is a convenience wrapper for store#push that will deserialize payloads"*. So this is nothing more than applying a Serializer on the provided data and pushing the normalized data into store.

A Serializer has to support `store.pushPayload()` by implementing a `pushPayload()` method. Not all Serializers shipped with Ember Data support it out of the box. `DS.JSONSerializer` does not. You could implement it or just call `normalizeResponse()` directly and passing the normalized response to `store.push()`. Implementing `pushPayload` may or may not be difficult depending on your concrete API implementation and the use cases you want to support, as you have to know the class of the primary model and the request type. Depending on your API this information may or may not be available in your payload.

Please note that there are ongoing discussions to deprecate `pushPayload`: https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/issues/357. This might be another argument for not implementing a custom solution for your DS.JSONSerializer but using `serializer.normalizeResponse()` and `store.push()`.

Comment: First of all thank you so much for the answer and I understand what you are trying to say about pushPayload and push methods but What I am trying to know is how to push a record into the store of a model which uses JSONSerializer or RESTSerializer as it's  Serializer .I don't know how to push a record of  a model which uses those two Serializer instead of JSONAPISerializer.Pushing a record of a JSONAPISerializer's model is working fine as it's model data already in JSON API format

Comment: I've extended my answer. Hope it's clear now that the Serializer used does not matter. It's just a matter of if your payload is already a *normalized JSON API document* or not.

Comment: Well jelhan I totally get it that the Serializer used does not matter as we have to choose the serializer which has a closer relationship or format to our backend API's response to normalize the payload but I just want to know what if I explicitly want to use a JSONSerializer then how should I add record to my ember store?

Comment: Can you add some of your existing serializer code to the question? Could help with seeing where the gaps are.

Comment: sure thing @ NullVoxPopuli

Comment: Model file[index.js]

import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.Model.extend({
    user: DS.belongsTo('user'),

    title: DS.attr("string"),
    body: DS.attr("string")
});

Adapter(index.js)

import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
    host: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com",
    pathForType() {
        return 'posts';
    }
});

Comment: import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
    normalizeResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
        console.log(payload)
        return this._super(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType);
    }
});

Comment: Now if I want to add a record or ember data into the ember store.It's not working it shows No such  method error

Comment: But when I add record to store for the models which has either JSONAPISerializer or RESTSerializer it's working fine.Can you help me with this one?

Comment: Updated my answer to make clear, that DS.JSONSerializer does not support pushPayload out of the box as it does not implement `pushPayload()`. Maybe Ember Data should throw a more meaningful error message in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this question ist five years old, but I came to the same issue and after long search found that the following is working in ember 5.4:

In serializers/application.js:

```
import JSONSerializer from '@ember-data/serializer/json';

export default class ApplicationSerializer extends JSONSerializer {
    pushPayload (store, payload) {
        let serializer = this
        let normalized_payload = serializer.normalizeResponse (
            store,
            store.modelFor (payload.model_name),
            payload.data,
            null,
            'updateRecord', // this works for new records and existing ones
            1 // for excatly one record
        )

        store.push (normalized_payload) // push payload to store
    }

}
```

And then I just call (here given with dummy-payload and model_name):

```
let payload = {"id": 123, "name": "testname", "other_fields_name": "otherfields_content"}
this.store.pushPayload ({model_name: 'my_model_name', data: payload})
```

I took the approach from here https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/4181#issuecomment-193236439 which will give more information, if you want to adopt this solution.